# jQuery cookie expires time is not correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set cookie using jquery.
but consoleLog date and expire date is not same.

```
function setCookie() {   
const date = new Date(); //Tue Oct 22 2019 17:45:53 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)   
const expires = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59); // Tue Oct 22 2019 23:59:59 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시) 
$.cookie('AAA', '', { expires }); 

}
```

But expire date is 2019-10-22T14:59:59.000Z
time is not same.
I found this issue in Chrome.
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I believe that there is no issue with the expiry date as the new date is expressed in UTC+0 time as seen by the 'Z' symbol, which is equivalent to the time that you have specified.

Comment: consoleLog date is Tue Oct 22 2019 23:59:59 GMT+0900.
actually cookie setting expire is 2019-10-22T14:59:59.000Z . the time is not same

Comment: You can try comparing `alert(expires.toISOString())` to the actual expiry date and it will produce the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer**

When you put a non-UTC date into the expires, then the javascript automatically convert the date to a GMT.

```
JavaScript Cookie expires time must be GMT/UTC
```

You may use following to have an UTC date that ends at 23:59:59

```js
const date = new Date(); 
const expires = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59));
console.log(expires.toUTCString());
```

**Update**  As per OP asked in comment to provide another approach so that he need not to use `getFullYear`, `getMonth` etc. methods. Here is how one can convert currentDate into UTC that ends at 23:59:59 without using `Date.UTC` and year/month functions:

```js
  var curDate = new Date();
  curDate.setUTCHours(23);
  curDate.setUTCMinutes(59);
  curDate.setUTCSeconds(59);
  console.log(curDate.toISOString())
```

Comment: I convert this code
const expires = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59).toISOString();
but error is working ' Uncaught TypeError: options.expires.toUTCString is not a function'

Comment: That won't help. Instead create a date that ends at 23:59:59 in UTC.

Comment: @zuuuuuuuu I have added code that uses `Date.UTC` method which you need. Enjoy :)

Comment: const expires = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);

Is this code UTC??
but cookie expires is setting session, not date

Comment: @zuuuuuuuu Yes, this construct a date in UTC and returns milliseconds. So we can further use that into `new Date()` to get a date object. 
`const expires = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59))`  is full code what you need

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: do you know how to convert utc more efficiently?? 
not using getFullYear,getMonth,getDate like methods not use!
help me